# Unable to detect ibeacon on iphone 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon, iphone-6

Hi  i have below code which works fine on iPod touch 5, but same code is not working on iPhone 6, i done research on same issue but i have not found anything useful. both devices have latest iOS.

Both devices have iOS 8

```
//  MapViewController.m
//  SidebarDemo
//
//  Created by Simon on 30/6/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Appcoda. All rights reserved.
//

#import "PetFinderViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"

@interface PetFinderViewController ()

@end

@implementation PetFinderViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(51/255.0) green:(51/255.0) blue:(51/255.0) alpha:1] ;

    self.title = @"Pet Finder";

    // Change button color
    //_sidebarButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.96f alpha:0.2f];

    // Set the side bar button action. When it's tapped, it'll show up the sidebar.
    _sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
    _sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

    // Set the gesture
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

    // Check if beacon monitoring is available for this device
    if (![CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Monitoring not available" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil]; [alert show]; return;
    }
    else
    {
        // Initialize location manager and set ourselves as the delegate
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;


        // Create a NSUUID
        NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"ebefd083-70a2-47c8-9837-e7b5634df524"];

        // Setup a new region AND start monitoring
        str_beaconIdentifier = @"in.appstute.marketing";
        self.myBeaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid major:1 minor:1 identifier:str_beaconIdentifier];

        self.myBeaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
        self.myBeaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = YES;
        self.myBeaconRegion.notifyOnExit = YES;

        [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];

        self.lbl_rangeStatus.text = @"Finding Your Pet";
        self.lbl_regionStatus.text = @"";
        self.lbl_distance.text = @"";
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't turn on ranging: Location services are not enabled.");
    }

    if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't turn on monitoring: Location services not authorised.");
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Core Location Delegate methods

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{

    UILocalNotification *notify = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notify.alertBody = @"You are near your Pet's region.";
    notify.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notify];

    // We entered a region, now start looking for our target beacons!
    //self.statusLabel.text = @"Finding beacons.";
    self.lbl_rangeStatus.text = @"Pet Found";
    self.lbl_regionStatus.text = @"Status : Entered Region";
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];

    //Opening camera
    /*if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

        //[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Camera Unavailable"
                                                       message:@"Unable to find a camera on your device."
                                                      delegate:nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        alert = nil;
    }*/
}


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    UILocalNotification *notify = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notify.alertBody = @"You are far away from your Pet's region.";
    notify.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notify];

    // Exited the region
    //self.statusLabel.text = @"None found.";
    self.lbl_rangeStatus.text = @"Pet Not Found";
    self.lbl_regionStatus.text = @"Status : Exited Region";
    [self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray*)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region
{
    CLBeacon *foundBeacon = [beacons firstObject];

    // Retrieve the beacon data from its properties
    NSString *uuid = foundBeacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString;
    NSString *major = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", foundBeacon.major];
    NSString *minor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", foundBeacon.minor];
    NSLog(@"uuid=%@, major=%@, minor=%@",uuid, major, minor);

    self.lbl_regionStatus.text = @"Status : Entered Region";

    if(foundBeacon.proximity==CLProximityImmediate)
    {
        NSLog(@"Immediate");
        //self.Lb_proxomity.text = @"Immediate";
    }
    else if (foundBeacon.proximity==CLProximityNear)
    {
        NSLog(@"Near");
        //self.Lb_proxomity.text = @"Near";
    }
    else if(foundBeacon.proximity==CLProximityFar)
    {
        NSLog(@"Far");
        //self.Lb_proxomity.text = @"Far";
    }
    else if(foundBeacon.proximity==CLProximityUnknown)
    {
        NSLog(@"Unknown");
        //self.Lb_proxomity.text = @"Unknown";
    }

    float actualDistance = foundBeacon.accuracy/10;
    NSLog(@"Distance = %f",actualDistance);
    if(actualDistance >= 0.0)
    {
        self.lbl_distance.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance : %.2f m",actualDistance];
    }
    //self.Lb_meter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",foundBeacon.accuracy];
    //self.Lb_centimeter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",(foundBeacon.accuracy*100)];
    //[self presentExhibitInfoWithMajorValue:foundBeacon.major.integerValue];

    //Calling this method to display strength for distance between user and the pet
    [self fn_showStrengthForDistanceBetweenUserAndPet:actualDistance];
}

#pragma mark - Check Background App Refresh status
-(BOOL)CanDeviceSupportAppBackgroundRefresh
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusAvailable) {
        NSLog(@"Background updates are available for the app.");
        return YES;
    }else if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusDenied)
    {
        NSLog(@"The user explicitly disabled background behavior for this app or for the whole system.");
        return NO;
    }else if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusRestricted)
    {
        NSLog(@"Background updates are unavailable and the user cannot enable them again. For example, this status can occur when parental controls are in effect for the current user.");
        return NO;
    }

    return NO;
}

#pragma mark - Check if monitoring region failed
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"monitoringDidFailForRegion - error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region{

    if (state == CLRegionStateInside) {


        //Start Ranging
        [manager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
    }

    else{

        //Stop Ranging
        [manager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
    }

}

@end
```

Comment: What exactly happens? Delegates not getting called at all? Empty list of beacons in didRange delegate? Could you double check if the app has the "always" authorization to use location services granted?

Comment: delegates are not getting called

Comment: only this gets called didChangeAuthorizationStatus
not anyone from below
didEnterRegion
didExitRegion
didDetermineState

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are having authorization issues on your iPhone.  Set a breakpoint or add NSLog statements to make sure this line is getting called:

```
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```

Do you get prompted?  If not, uninstall and reinstall.

Also, check in setting that Bluetooth and Location services are enabled on the phone, and check settings on your app to see that location services are actually enabled for it.

Comment: whatever you have suggested all i have done already, again done to make sure

Comment: he sorry, i missed Bluetooth, bluetooth was not turned on. silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

You need to set one of

`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`
or 
`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` when requesting location updates (even with iBeacons).

If you don't, in iOS 8, this will fail silently.